# Issue with rounding off the value in robot framework

Tags: math, robotframework, computational-geometry

is there any way in robot framework that 1297395061.06 value can be evaluated whether it's in Million, or Billion or in Thousand.

if its in Billion should get as a result 1.30B

Comment: what have you currently tried?

Comment: ${var}= 1297395061.06
${expectedResult}=  evaluate ${var}/100000000
${finalResult}=  catenate ${expectedResult}B
log $finalResult}

getting 12.9739506106B

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the BuiltIn keywords like this

`${var}=  convert to number  1297395061.06`

`${b}=    evaluate  ${var}/100000000`

`${c}    convert to integer    ${b}`

In this case, `${c}` would get the value 12